# Javascript: Pass event AND element reference

Tags: javascript, function, events, onkeypress

I want an input field which calls a javascript function, if a key is pressed. But I'm not able to pass the event as well as an element reference. I can either pass the event:

```
<input type="text" name="chmod" value="644" onkeypress="chmod(e)">
```

or pass the element reference:

```
<input type="text" name="chmod" value="644" onkeypress="chmod(this)">
```

If I try to pass both there occurs an error:

```
<input type="text" name="chmod" value="644" onkeypress="chmod(e, this)">

Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined
```

Is there any way to pass both, the event and a reference to the element?

Cheers, Marco

Comment: Do you have access to use a JavaScript library like jQuery? This is a good example (cross browser pain) where being able to use a library lets you define your event handlers separately and bind them to the field(s) you want to use them on... overcoming the limitations of IE's legacy global event object, and manually passing the event in other browsers via inline event handlers. jQuery's keypress event handler: http://api.jquery.com/keypress/ for example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="chmod" value="644" onkeypress="chmod(event, this)">
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have a reference to the element in the event: `event.target`.

Comment: Thank you. That is also a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do the following:

```
<input type="text" name="chmod" value="644" onkeypress="chmod">
```

Then your js:

```
function chmod(e) {
    var element = e.target;
    ...
}
```

Comment:  I am looking for this solution exactly

Answer (score 0):

The `this` keyword is already in the function

```
<script>
function chmod(e) {
    var elem = this;
}
</script>

<input type="text" name="chmod" value="644" onkeypress="chmod">
```